# Okta - AUtomate users and group assignments via Terraform

Tags: terraform, okta

Terraform Version

Terraform v1.3.2

```
provider registry.terraform.io/okta/okta v3.36.0
```

Affected Resource(s)

```
okta_app_group_assignments
okta_group_memberships
okta_user
```

I am trying to configure and implement Okta SSO / MFA via Terraform. Reasoning is because I want to manage my organisation accounts and app integrations via terraform as I am wanting to achieve an automated approach to creating a user > assigning user to a group dependent on department > assign apps to user all through a github repo where the user can change the auto .tfvars file, input their user information and request via a PR (approved by myself who is a super admin).

This will be very cool, as the config will ultimately automate group assignment and apps dependent on the department inputted.

I am struggling discovering a nice easy way to loop over an iterate user / group ids with a conditional on where, lets say;

okta_user.user.department == okta_group_description (this would be very cool)

I have tried conditional logic with an if statement similar to code below and had no luck.

The code below may not necessarily show a clear understanding, but almost an attempt to get this working.

If anyone could aid or show configured code for my use case. That would be brill :)
Actual Behavior

errors on multiple different reasons on my attempts to configure like this.
Steps to Reproduce

I have also tried adding users like this in the group_membership resource:

```
["${okta_user.user[each.key].id}"]
```

But get an error:

```
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on main.tf line 115, in resource "okta_group_memberships" "ba":
│  115:   users = ["${okta_user.user[each.key].id}"]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is "BA"
│     │ okta_user.user is object with 2 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Terraform Configuration Files

```
resource "okta_group" "groups" {
  for_each = var.groupList
  name        = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
}

resource "okta_user" "user"{
  #for_each = {for i, v in var.userList: i => v}
  for_each = var.userList
  first_name    = each.value.first_name
  last_name     = each.value.last_name
  display_name  = each.value.display_name
  email         = each.value.email
  login         = each.value.login
  department    = each.value.department
  organization  = each.value.organization
}

resource "okta_group_memberships" "devops" {
for_each = {for group, n in var.groupList: group => n if n.name == "DevOps"}
  group_id = okta_group.groups[each.key].id
  users = []
  
  depends_on = [okta_group.groups]
}

resource "okta_app_group_assignments" "everyone" {
  for_each = { for k in compact([for k, v in var.samlAppList: v.admin_note ? k : ""]): k => var.samlAppList[k] }

    app_id = okta_app_saml.saml_apps[each.key].id
  group {
    id = okta_group.everyone.id
    priority = 1
  }
}

#variables.tf
variable "groupList"{
  type = map(object({
    name          = string
    description   = string
  }))
}

#auto.tfvars

groupList = {
  devOps = {
    name : "DevOps"
    description : "DevOps"
  },
  DS = {
    name : "DS"
    description : "DS"
  },
  BA = {
    name : "BA"
    description : "BA"
  },
  FrontEnd = {
    name : "FrontEnd"
    description : "FrontEnd"
  },
  BackEnd = {
    name : "BackEnd"
    description : "BackEnd"
  }
}

#User Information
variable "userList" {
  type = map(object({
    first_name   = string
    last_name    = string
    display_name = string
    email        = string
    login        = string
    department   = string
    organization = string
  }))
  }

#User Details
userList = { 
   tom = { 
    first_name : ""
    last_name : ""
    display_name : ""
    email : ""
    login : ""
    department : ""
    organization : ""
  }
}
```

Comment: And where is the `okta_user` resource?

Comment: Amended code section

Comment: Great, how about the variable you used for creating users, `userList`? :)

Comment: Added. Thank you for noticing. I am using a map type as for each doesn't iterate over with a list type.

Comment: It does with type casting to a set. There is a built-in `toset` function.

Comment: Is there a way to map between the users and the DevOps group?

Comment: Oh cool. Thanks for that knowledge. I am happy with the lists as they are working. I think the issue lies with myi attempt on the for_each. I ultimately want one resource block for group_membership and group_app_assignment. So, when a colleague wants an account they add their user information. When user.department == group.description it automates and self assigns apps.

Comment: users = [] takes a list of ids. So I have tried to pass in the ids but get the error stated. It doesn't seem to like it because there is a for_each under the okta_group and can't pass in the ids?

Comment: Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Sure. It's still unclear to me how would you map between the group and the user? Meaning that the `for_each` used in groups does not have the same keys as users do. So currently I don't see a way to map between the two.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I was hoping the value would work, as users.department and group.name is the same. As that's what I am trying to achieve. But don't think its possible... I have raised a use case support ticket with Okta to see if they can help.

Comment: Hello, in regards to this issue. I am struggling to pass the okta_user.user.id into the users list. On the group_membership resource. Do you have any idea how to get the ids created from the list and place them into here?